# Meteor: modify data already being published with a method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I currently have a publication that looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish("publicRoomInfo", function (roomID) {
    return Rooms.find({_id: roomID}, {fields: {
        "peopleArr.name": 1, 
        "peopleArr.hasSubmitted": 1, 
    }});
});
```

As you can see I am only publishing two fields within the `peopleArr` array:

`name` and `hasSubmitted`

Later, however, I want to **add** to this publication another field called `userKey`.

So my goal would be for the publication to look like this:

```
Meteor.publish("publicRoomInfo", function (roomID) {
    return Rooms.find({_id: roomID}, {fields: {
        "peopleArr.name": 1, 
        "peopleArr.hasSubmitted": 1, 
        "peopleArr.userKey": 1,
    }});
});
```

Is there any way I can modify the publication in a method? Currently, if I try to republish I receive an error telling me it is a duplicate publication that has been ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a little trick like this:

```
Meteor.publish("publicRoomInfo", function (roomID, userKey) {
  let fields = {}
  fields["peopleArr.name"] = 1;
  fields["peopleArr.hasSubmitted"] = 1;

  //Checks whether userKey is set to true or false and adding it into fields object.
  userKey ? fields["peopleArr.userKey"] = 1 : '';

  return Rooms.find({_id: roomID}, {fields: fields});
});
```

Here you can tell Meteor subscribe if you want to add the userKey or not simple pass an argument of true or false. 
Although i recommend you to know which fields you want to fetch in the first place. and keep together.